# is it possible to change colour of only one view controller's navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I tried changing the colour of navigation bar in one controller but it changes colour of navigation bar in every controller.

Comment: Update question with your code

Comment: Change color in view will appear and view will disappear.  Or push a new navigation item for this view controller.

Comment: //self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red

Answer (score 0):

Don't use segue type as push/ show.

You can try present type. This will help you.

Here you will create a new `navigationController`. So, you can customise it for single viewController.

I hope it help full for you.

Comment: how to create a new navigation controller?

Comment: in storyboard select view controller you want to add inside navigationcontroller -> Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller

Answer (score 0):

on your view controller apply below methods:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated: animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red //current new color
}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated: animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white  //other vc's color
}
```

Comment: the navigation bar colour of the next controller is takin 5-6 sec to change the colour.